# How to empty the DSpace assetstore?

Tags: dspace

For testing purposes I have made a clone of a DSpace 5.5 server. 
To spare disk room used by this clone I have removed a collection which contained several thousand items.
After this action the assetstore directory is still very full, although there is only one collection left with just one item as content.
How can I empty the assetstore from the items belonging to the removed collection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `dspace cleanup` command line script removes deleted bitstreams from the assetstore.

https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Storage+Layer#StorageLayer-Cleanup

```
dspace/bin/dspace cleanup -h
usage: Cleanup
 -h,--help      Help
 -l,--leave     Leave database records but delete file from assetstore
 -v,--verbose   Provide verbose output
```

---

edit (may 19):
If you've got a massive amount of deleted bitstreams the command can take a long time to complete. There is another way:

```
$ psql -c "select internal_id from bitstream where deleted=true" > deleted_bitstreams   
$ while read internal_id; do rm $HOME/dspace/assetstore/${internal_id:0:2}/${internal_id:2:2}/${internal_id:4:2}/$internal_id; done < deleted_bitstreams
```

You can make sure the paths are fine by running the command with `ls` instead of `rm` first

Comment: Thanks Antoine. That did the job.

Comment: Peter, you may like to mark Antoine's answer as "accepted" to make it immediately obvious that it's the way to go.